# Can I use in my code shared memory for nVidia Quadro KxxxxM (MXM) mobile GPUs?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

As I can see, on [google and many sites](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%89&oq=%D0%BF%D1%89&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.399j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=nvidia%20quadro%20mxm%20no%20shared%20memory), there is ["Shared Memory: no"](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Quadro-K1000M.76894.0.html) for the nVidia Quadro KXXXXM - Mobile GPU (MXM).

But if I want to write CUDA C/C++ for these cards, can I use shared memory in my code? And if I can, then what will happen if I do so - will it use global GPU-RAM instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use shared memory on your Quadro (K-series) mobile GPU.

If you want confirmation of this, run the [`1_Utilities/deviceQuery`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery) sample code.  Look for "Total amount of shared memory per block:" and it will report 49152 bytes, the same as most other modern GPUs.

The "Shared Memory: No" reference in those links is not referring to CUDA shared memory.  It is referring to a feature or capability of some graphics devices to use some of the system memory as if it were graphics memory, for graphics operations (i.e. not CUDA computing).  Those references are not relevant to the term "shared memory" as used by CUDA.